# Search for matching value in matrix and retrieve value from first row?

Tags: excel

I have an ID in cell `A1` in `sheet1`.

I want to match this ID with the same ID in `sheet2`. The IDs in `sheet2` are in cells `A2:Z45`. I want to retrieve the value from row 1 in the column where the matching ID was found.

So it's similar to a Vlookup, but it is horisontal and I want to search for matches in a matrix.

Is this possible?

Comment: Will there ever be more than one occurrence of your chosen search value within the range A2:Z45?

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/482057/excel-formula-what-is-the-equivalent-of-match-but-for-multiple-columns) and subsequent answer may help you

Comment: @xor lx: There will never be more than 1 occurance

Comment: @asongtoruin: Thank you. That solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try in `sheet1`, entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=INDEX(sheet2!A1:Z45,1,MAX(IF(sheet2!A2:Z45=A1,COLUMN(sheet2!A1:Z45))))
```

Note this only returns the column Label for the last match found.